# Chef / Vagrant - Kitchen cant connect to Update Jenkins

Tags: linux, java, chef, vagrant, jenkins

Iam getting crazy with Chef, Vagrant and Test-Kitchen.

We have an customized Jenkins Cookbook, it works on "normal" Clients without Cooperate Network Proxys, but fails behind with the following error.

```
 - create new file /tmp/kitchen/cache/jenkins-cli.jar
             - update content in file /tmp/kitchen/cache/jenkins-cli.jar from none to 0b49c2
             (new content is binary, diff output suppressed)


           * remote_file[/tmp/kitchen/cache/update-center.json] action create_if_missing     
       [2015-05-11T16:28:32+00:00] ERROR: Error connecting to http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/updates/update-center.json, retry 1/5
       [2015-05-11T16:30:43+00:00] ERROR: Error connecting to http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/updates/update-center.json, retry 2/5
       [2015-05-11T16:32:54+00:00] ERROR: Error connecting to http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/updates/update-center.json, retry 3/5
       [2015-05-11T16:35:06+00:00] ERROR: Error connecting to http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/updates/update-center.json, retry 4/5
       [2015-05-11T16:37:17+00:00] ERROR: Error connecting to http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/updates/update-center.json, retry 5/5
```

All other ressources are downloaded without any problems (using vagrant proxy plugin). The Host is based on Windows 7, the guest is CentOS 6.6

Problem identfied: jenkins-cli.jar is not using system proxy, iam not able to download plugin when logged in to the VM. But no solution found so far (;

Comment: Configuring the proxy in test-kitchen should help you (see https://gist.github.com/fnichol/7551540 for the `driver.http_proxy` variables).

Comment: No changes (-: still fails at the update-center.json .. i have no idea why everything else works.. the only "interessting" is, that it is an redirect.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick workaround, simply set the attribute:

```
default['jenkins']['master']['mirror'] = 'http://example.lan'
```

to point to a local HTTP server, where the `http://example.lan/updates/update-center.json` is an empty JSON file (or, generally, the server returns 200 for the request `GET /updates/update-center.json`).

Also, please have a look at [this line of code](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/6af3ba73aace221bf959d3996404219364405eab/libraries/_helper.rb#L80).